# @ManyToOne Update/Delete Object in cascade, Parent - Children

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm using DTO's with Hibernate 4.2, but I have problems to Update in Cascade my DTO, concretly when I delete a Children, I can't update this change.

I have @Bidirectional Relationship like here:

Book 1-M - Page - 1-M Line

**class Book**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book")
    private Set<Page> pages;
```

**class Page**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    private Book book;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "page")
    private Set<Line> lines;
```

When I receive the DTO I do a mapping to the Hibernate Object to implement the changes, but in the case when a Children has for instance 4 objects, and I delete 2, when I update the Parent, Hibernate don't do nothing.

```
public Long updateBook(BookDTO BookDto) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Book Book = new Book();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Book = (Book) session.get(Book.class, BookDto.getId());

            Book.setTitle(BookDto.getTitle());
            Book.setDescription(BookDto.getDescription());

            //Pages
            if (BookDto.getPages() != null){

                Set<PageDTO> pagesDto = BookDto.getPages();
                Set<Page> pages = new HashSet<Page>();

                for (PageDTO pageDto : pagesDto) {
                        Page page = new Page();
                        page.setId(pageDto.getId());
                        page.setSequence(pageDto.getSequence());
                        page.setBook(Book);

                        Set<LineDTO> linesDto = pageDto.getLines();
                        Set<Line> lines = new HashSet<Line>(); 

                        for (LineDTO lineDto : linesDto) {
                            Line line = new Line ();
                            linesetId(lineDto.getId());
                            linesetPage(page);

                            lines.add(line);    
                      }
                  }
                    page.setLines(Lines);
                    pages.add(page);
                }                           
                Book.setPages(pages);   
                }                           
            }
            session.update(Book);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error updating Book :" + e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

With this code I set to my Object Book only the info from the DTO, in the case where the User has deleted three "Linies" in the object Page, I dont set this info, I guess when I update the Object Book, Hibernate have to delete automatically the object's are not in relationship with the parent Object, before to use the DTO, this example work perfectly with the model class I guess the problem come from the detached Objects.

Answer (score 1):

The orphan removal is set to false by default.

If you want to remove orphans when updating collection in **Parent** class, you should declare that in the **@OnetoMany** annotation at **Parent** level.

In your case, you may want to update mapping as follows:

**Class Book:**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book", orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Page> pages;
```

**Class Page:**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "page", orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Line> lines;
```

For more info, please refer to [Hibernate 4.3 Reference example one-to-many with orphan removal](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#example-one-to-many-with-orphan-removal)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Davide Rossi, In terms of Perfomance what is better, make this with OrphanRemoval=true or the OldSchool Method with HSQL? Finally I have to map the DTO to the Model Entities, with HSQL will be a few lines more and more secure than OprhanRemoval, what do you think?

Comment: Imho, the more you reuse, the less problems you'll have in the future. 
Using orphanRemoval is basically re-using code already written, tested, someway hopefully optimized by Hibernate developers. If I choose to use Hibernate, I take advantage of all that it offers.